# ASP.NET MVC 5 change database name

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hy!

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC 5. I try to change the default database name. But I don't know how. My goal is to have only one database for the whole application.

My actual working **Web.Config**:

```
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="DataSource=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-SqlTest-20131122100021.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-SqlTest-20131122100021;Integrated Security=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

This **Web.Config** file should look like this and should work ^^ (actual I get a error that the database could not be created and the physical name may be incorrect)

```
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="DataSource=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=Example.mdf;Initial Catalog=Example;Integrated Security=True"
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `|DataDirectory|\` before `Example.mdf`, like below:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
    connectionString="DataSource=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Example.mdf;Initial Catalog=Example;Integrated Security=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```